# Where do Android constants live?

Tags: java, android, constants

The documentation for LinearLayout gives the value for constants in the documentation. Can these be brought in from an existing package/namespace or do they need to be defined at the class or application level?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#VERTICAL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, constants are always (static) members of some class; in this case, `android.widget.LinearLayout`. To refer to it, you would write `LinearLayout.VERTICAL` in your source code, after importing the class (`import android.widget.LinearLayout;`) at the top of the source file. Or, if that is the *only* time you ever mention `LinearLayout`, you could write `android.widget.LinearLayout.VERTICAL` without any import, but this is uncommon style.

Comment: makes perfect sense once you know the convention.